# Count unique values in a column of an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count, unique, array-column

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [
    1 => ['A' => '1', 'C' => 'TEMU3076746'],
    2 => ['A' => '2', 'C' => 'FCIU5412720'],
    3 => ['A' => '3', 'C' => 'TEMU3076746'],
    4 => ['A' => '4', 'C' => 'TEMU3076746'],
    5 => ['A' => '5', 'C' => 'FCIU5412720']
];
```

My goal is to count the distinct values in the `C` column of the 2-dimensional array.

The total rows in the array is found like this: `count($arr)` (which is `5`).

How can I count the number of rows which contain a unique value in the 'C' column?

If I removed the duplicate values in the `C` column, there would only be: `TEMU3076746` and `FCIU5412720`

My desired output is therefore `2`.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this simplest one will be helpful. Here we are using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/853164)

```
echo count(
        array_unique(
                array_column($data,"C")));
```

**Result:** `2`

Comment: Just saying, can also use `array_flip` in the place of `array_unique`. +1

Comment: that's some dark evil usage of array_flip ... as long as the values are strings or integers it works.

Answer (score 2):

combine [array_map](http://php.net/array_map), [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique), [count](http://php.net/count)

```
$array = [ /* your array */ ];
$count = count(
    array_unique(
        array_map(function($element) { 
            return $element['C']; 
        }, $array))))
```

or use array_column as suggested by sahil gulati, array_map can do more stuff which probably isn't needed here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar need and I used a slightly different method.

I have several events where teams are participating and I need to know how many teams there are in each event. In other words, I don't need to only know how many  distinct item "C" there are, but how many items `TEMU3076746` and `FCIU5412720` there are.

The code will then be as is

```
$nbCs = array_count_values ( array_column ( $array, 'C' ) );
```

`$nbCs` will issue an array of `values = Array([TEMU3076746] => 3 [FCIU5412720] => 2)`

See example in sandbox [Sandbox code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/048f9d318b92f1332a8ecaa0e8e8efced2e8dcce)

Comment: This answer is 1. Doing more counting work than the task requires and 2. Does not count the generated elements.   This answer would need the additional call of `count()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=array();
$data=[
       1 => [
             'A' => '1'
             'C' => 'TEMU3076746'
            ]

       2 => [
             'A' => '2'
             'C' => 'FCIU5412720'
            ]

       3 => [
             'A' => '3'
             'C' => 'TEMU3076746'
            ]
       
       4 => [
            'A' => '4'
            'C' => 'TEMU3076746'
            ]

       5 => [
             'A' => '5'
             'C' => 'FCIU5412720'
           ]
        ];

 $total_value=count(
    array_unique(
            array_column($data,"C")));
echo $total_value;
```

Comment: Please only add an answer if you have something unique and valuable to add to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Most concisely, use `array_column()`'s special ability to assign new first level keys using the targeted column's values.  This provides the desired effect of uniqueness because arrays cannot contain duplicate keys on the same level.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0bSOR))

```
echo count(array_column($arr, 'C', 'C')); // 2
```

To be perfectly clear, `array_column($arr, 'C', 'C')` produces:

```
array (
  'TEMU3076746' => 'TEMU3076746',
  'FCIU5412720' => 'FCIU5412720',
)
```

This would also work with `array_column($arr, null, 'C')`, but that create a larger temporary array.

---

p.s. There is a fringe case that may concern researchers who are seeking unique float values.  Assigning new associative keys using float values is inappropriate/error-prone because the keys will lose precision (become truncated to integers).

In that fringe case with floats, fallback to the less performant technique: `count(array_unique(array_column($arr, 'B)))` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/6ae1o)